# How to retrieve saved sets from excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, set, xlrd

I have saved data as `sets` in an `excel` file using `xlsxwriter` in `python 2.7`. For retrieving part, when I print the file first row set, it is something like:
`set([u'1707242470', u'643602863', u'1677452893])` and the type is `unicode`. I converted the `unicode` to `set` and `pop` it, but I see nothing when printing it. the question is how I can retrieve the saved sets and pop them correctly. for example, the first pop is `1707242470`. here is my code:

```
  from xlrd import open_workbook
  book1 = open_workbook('processed_data.xlsx')
  sheet1 = book1.sheet_by_name('sheet');
  # I want to pop the first element of my set in my first row set third column which is 1707242470 
  print (set)(sheet1.cell(0, 3).value).pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that cell/sheet indexes are zero-based.
Also no need to convert single cell value to set and use pop()

EDIT:

```
    print sheet1.cell(0,0).value
    print '{}'.format(sheet1.cell(0,0).value)
```

Comment: what do you mean? I need to rich the elements and use them in the next!

Comment: so how to get first element?